# How enable style Menu in Windows 10 using Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, menu, manifest

All components are stylized, except the menu that has this gray background. In Windows 10, it turns white.

[image]

I have tried the following solutions:

- Add XPMan
- Create file res, with the following information:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
   <assemblyIdentity
      name="MyCompany"
      processorArchitecture="*"
      version="2.7.0.0"
      type="win32"/>
   <description>MySoftware</description>
   <dependency>
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
         />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </dependency>
   <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <security>
         <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel
               level="asInvoker"
               uiAccess="False"/>
         </requestedPrivileges>
      </security>
   </trustInfo>
   <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
      <application>
         <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
         <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
         <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
         <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
         <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
      </application>
   </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Does your menu use any glyphs or images?

Comment: No, is only menu with letters

Comment: I'm struggling to reproduce this.

Comment: This problem only occurs with Delphi 7. In newer versions like Delphi Tokyo works perfectly

Comment: As I said, I'm struggling to reproduce this

Comment: What is build Delphi 7? Used 7.0 Build 8.1 Enterprise

Comment: I'm also perplexed by the style of that button. What type is it?

Comment: TButton default delphi